# how to continue the graph line when missing series of data in middle of highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts

when use 'null' single line point is missing

when i use ''  entire line of chart is showing in points

i want to continue the line even though middle some data is missing.

Please help me to get the regular line.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLepdyz0/1/).

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, '', 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8,null, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }]
```

Comment: Quick Google turned up this: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.connectNulls . But I don't know anything about highcharts.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, be sure to use `null` points. String points like `''` will break the chart.

The solution provided by @Benno Zeeman is correct, use [connectNulls](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.connectNulls).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LLepdyz0/2/